# Is this a disk brake mount?

Tags: disc-brake

This is a picture of 2011 scott contessa 60:
[image]
Is this some kind of disk brake mount? If yes - what type is it? I've got an avid bb7 (mtn) caliper and it'd be nice to install it here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is a mount for a kick stand.

See this picture
[image: inline image]

Comment: thanks! not an answer I hoped to get, but I guess it's correct

Comment: The truth doesn't care about our hopes, dreams or feelings unfortunately haha